# Data structure to represent adjacency list for graph, when receiving ambiguous specs

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I am designing an application which should be based on graphs.
I am not sure which is the best way to represent the graph adjacency list  in memory. The requirements from the customer are quite vague, so I must make some several assumptions. The nodes of the graphs are some IDs, but I am not sure if the IDs are sequential or not. What does the graph theory say, when it comes to general specifications?
If they are sequential, the number of nodes (N) should also limit the max IDs, and basically it is ensured that the IDs will cover the interval ***1,2…N***. See option A below.
If they are not sequential, the IDs could jump from 1 to e.g. 11, and may skip some natural numbers in the specification. See option B below.
Beside ID, there is also a c++ data structure, where I store multiple info ( payload, connected edges etc.)
There are two options left for my algorithm:

**A.**  Represent the graph as a vector< Data > , and index of vector will mean to the nodeID.

**B.**  Represent the graph as a map , where Node ID is the key, and Data is the storage value.

Map would allow me having random IDs, let’s say that the input data is given randomly.

The literature ( e.g. DFS, BFS or other graph articles) is mostly considering option A, where node IDs fully cover an interval ***[1..N]***. I would also go for this option, as it represents a commonly agreed notation.
Then, add this to the documentation/precondition section of my application.

What is the best option to proper cover customer’s ambiguous specifications?

Comment: In the first place, you must ask the customer if the IDs are sequential.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose to represent a your graph as a combination of your two listed options: have a `Node` structure that contains two members - an integer `label` and a the other struct you need.

The graph will store a `std::vector<Node*> nodes;`. However, given the restriction that a node's label will not match its position in the above vector, you will need to store the correspondence between label and vector indexes in a `std::map<int, int> corresp;`

Given this structure, if you need to access the Node* with a label value of 11, you would do `Node* node = nodes[corresp[label]];`

Also, the label could be any other type, for instance a `std::string`. The only modification that needs to be done is to change the key type of the map to `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: sequential IDs. Then you may store the nodes in an array in such a way that the indexes correspond to the IDs.

Case 2: sparse IDs.

Usually the representation of the nodes of a graph allows them to have a payload (attributes), such as the ID. If you don't need to access the nodes by ID, use an array and you are done.

If you do need to access the nodes by ID, use a dictionary (map) to establish the correspondence. You can also store the nodes directly in the dictionary, but node enumeration or sorting will be harder.

Answer (score 0):

I usually recommend identifying things with (maybe smart) pointers if they are objects, since that's the mechanism that C/C++ provides to identify objects.

Fundamentally, your graph consists of a number of nodes and edges, so you would generally have something like:

```
class Node {
    int id;
    Data data;
    std::vector<Node *> edges;
}
```

Then, in your `Graph` class, you will need some kind of map for every *other* way you need to access nodes.  You will probably need to be able to find nodes by id, so the graph class will need some kind of index for that -- a `vector<Node *> nodesById` for dense ids or a `map<int,Node*> nodesById` for sparse ids.  Which one to choose should *not* be an important decision that has a lot of consequences.  Add a method `Node *getNodeById(int id)`, and then you can change the representation whenever you want.  Always remember that, in software development, when a decision doesn't have an obvious answer, or when the best answer is likely to change in the future, then **making it easy to change your mind is much better than making the right choice**.

As people add requirements to your graph, you may need to access nodes in different ways and may have to add more kinds of indexes to support those particular use cases.

Two jobs you will need to do with your graph are construction and destruction.  Construction will probably require that `nodesById` index.  Destruction will definately require some way to enumerate all the nodes, and whichever representation you choose for `nodesById` will suffice for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map of vectors. Something like this:

```
Map<int,vector<Node *>>;
```

The key in this map would be your node id. The corresponding vector has the first entry as your corresponding node of that particular Id and then all the edges from that Id node.

Suppose, your graph has a node with id 2, and this node has its edges with nodes with id 3,4 and 6.

So your entry corresponding to the key 2 in your map would be a vector, that has its first entry as node with id 2, then next entry as node of id 3, then with 4 and then at last with node 6.

Your each vector entry of Node could look similar to this:

```
struct Node {
 int id,
 InfoData obj;
}
```